# How can I use a PFLoginViewController with the REST API instead of PFUser?

Tags: parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller, pfuser

I'm trying to build my Parse iOS project in a way that'll be more easy to migrate later on for the client should he desire it.

To that end, I'm trying to use the REST API instead of relying on PFUser and PFObjects.

But I love the PFLoginViewController-- it's such a time saver. Is there a way I can use that pre-built login/sign-up flow with the REST API instead of PFUser?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that u could use it without PFUser but u could create similar to that and time will be consumed.

Still One thing might work out, check this [link](https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views) and I hope you have already but this will show how to integrate the PFLoginViewcontroller so in that they have **logInView** which will provide you access to all component like loginButton, usernameTextField, passTextField and etc. So you could access to these component your own explicit component.

Like, you could create your own UIButton(namely, logInBtn with action selector and all) then access it to logInView.LogInButton = logInBtn(your own button) and in this button's action you could make Rest api calls for login, and similarly for other component which needs to be modified for your requirement.